# sitecore_web_index corrupted on Content Delivery server

Tags: configuration, indexing, lucene

What does the Lucene `sitecore_web_index` do on the Content Delivery server?
How can it become corrupted?

Comment: Please add version of Sitecore that you use + more information on how index corruption was realized. Add all relevant log entries with exception (best as text not as picture)

Answer (score 1):

The `sitecore_web_index` holds the searchable index for the `web` database. It is the same as the `sitecore_master_index`, except that the crawler will use the `web` database when it builds the index. This is everything related to the published website.

As for what it's used for, that will depend on your implementation. If your code implements any searching with the Sitecore ContentSearch API and your site is configured to use Lucene, then all the search API code *should* be hitting that Lucene index.

As for corruption, there are many things that could cause that. To find out you could use the [CheckIndex](https://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/) tool that is available for Lucene. It may give you better indications of what the corruption might be and what is causing it.

References:

- [Sitecore: Search Index Descriptions](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_index_descriptions)
- [Detailed description of the ContentSearchAPI](https://soen.ghost.io/a-re-introduction-to-the-contentsearch-api-in-sitecore-part-1/)